# Configure VLAN with DHCP traffic properly forwarded

Tags: vlan, dhcp, hp, juniper-ex, meraki

I have a windows DHCP server in VLAN 10 and I have wireless clients in VLAN 288.  The VLANs are defined in my Juniper EX-4600 and the VLANs are tagged/trunked all the way to the Meraki APs.

```
[DHCP]---[EX-4600]---[EX-4300]--[HP5130]---[Meraki APs]
```

There are VLANs that are working and VLANs that do not and they all seem to have the same configuration with the exception of the subnet.

The only thing that I have found in searching for a solution was on the juniper KB that said to configure IP helpers, but none of the other VLANs have that and they work, so I don't think that is the solution.

```
## Last commit: 2018-07-26 01:20:45 UTC by root
version 14.1X53-D40.8;
system {
    processes {
        dhcp-service {
            traceoptions {
                file dhcp_logfile size 10m;
                level all;
                flag all;
            }
        }
        app-engine-virtual-machine-management-service {
            traceoptions {
                level notice;
                flag all;
            }
        }
    }
}
chassis {
    redundancy {
        graceful-switchover;
    }
}
interfaces {
    interface-range VLAN4 {
        member-range ge-1/0/5 to ge-1/0/11;
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members 4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xe-0/0/23 {
        ether-options {
            flow-control;
        }
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                interface-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ 1 3 10 100 140-141 172 176 210-213 230-232 234 236 238 270 280 288 ];
                }
                storm-control default;
            }
        }
    }
    em1 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet;
        }
    }
    irb {
        unit 0 {
            family inet;
        }
        unit 1 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.1.100/24;
            }
        }
        unit 2 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.11.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 3 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.10.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 4 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.9.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 5 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.15.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 6 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.35.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 8 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.36.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 9 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.37.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 10 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.75.2/24;
            }
        }
        unit 11 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.76.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 15 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.8.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 20 {
            family inet {
                address 10.0.0.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 100 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.100.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 111 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.111.6/24;
            }
        }
        unit 130 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.30.1/23;
            }
        }
        unit 132 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.32.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 133 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.33.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 136 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.36.1/22;
            }
        }
        unit 138 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.56.1/21;
            }
        }
        unit 140 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.40.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 141 {
            family inet {
                address 172.16.41.142/29;
            }
        }
        unit 170 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.72.1/22;
            }
        }
        unit 171 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.76.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 172 {
            family inet {
                address 172.26.88.10/21;
            }
        }
        unit 176 {
            family inet {
                address 172.16.41.177/29;
            }
        }
        unit 180 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.80.1/23;
            }
        }
        unit 188 {
            family inet {
                address 10.1.88.1/21;
            }
        }
        unit 210 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.10.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 211 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.11.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 212 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.12.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 213 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.13.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 230 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.30.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 231 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.31.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 232 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.32.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 234 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.34.1/23;
            }
        }
        unit 236 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.36.1/23;
            }
        }
        unit 238 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.56.1/21;
            }
        }
        unit 270 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.72.1/22;
            }
        }
        unit 271 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.76.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 280 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.80.1/23;
            }
        }
        unit 288 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.88.1/21;
            }
        }
        unit 311 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.11.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 331 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.31.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 332 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.32.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 334 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.34.1/23;
            }
        }
        unit 336 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.36.1/23;
            }
        }
        unit 338 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.56.1/21;
            }
        }
        unit 370 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.72.1/22;
            }
        }
        unit 371 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.76.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 380 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.80.1/23;
            }
        }
        unit 388 {
            family inet {
                address 10.103.88.1/21;
            }
        }
    }
    vme {
        unit 0 {
            family inet;
        }
    }
}
snmp {
    name HSServerRoom-4600;
    description HSServerRoom-4600;
    location "HS Server Room";
    contact "jgaspard@kirbyvillecisd.org";
    client-list list0 {
        192.168.75.0/24;
    }
    community public {
        authorization read-only;
        client-list-name list0;
    }
    trap-group kcisd-traps {
        destination-port 162;
        targets {
            192.168.75.29;
        }
    }
}
forwarding-options {
    storm-control-profiles default {
        all;
    }
    analyzer {
        INTERNET_IN {
            input {
                ingress {
                    interface ge-1/0/0.0;
                }
                egress {
                    interface ge-1/0/0.0;
                }
            }
            output {
                interface ge-1/0/2.0;
            }
        }
    }
    dhcp-relay {
        server-group {
            dhcp_servers {
                192.168.75.12;
            }
        }
        group group1 {
            active-server-group dhcp_servers;
            interface irb.1;
            interface irb.2;
            interface irb.3;
            interface irb.4;
            interface irb.5;
            interface irb.6;
            interface irb.8;
            interface irb.9;
            interface irb.10;
            interface irb.11;
            interface irb.15;
            interface irb.100;
            interface irb.111;
            interface irb.130;
            interface irb.132;
            interface irb.133;
            interface irb.136;
            interface irb.138;
            interface irb.170;
            interface irb.180;
            interface irb.188;
            interface irb.210;
            interface irb.211;
            interface irb.212;
            interface irb.213;
            interface irb.230;
            interface irb.231;
            interface irb.232;
            interface irb.234;
            interface irb.236;
            interface irb.238;
            interface irb.270;
            interface irb.280;
            interface irb.288;
            interface irb.311;
            interface irb.331;
            interface irb.332;
            interface irb.334;
            interface irb.338;
            interface irb.370;
            interface irb.380;
            interface irb.388;
        }
    }
}
routing-options {
    nonstop-routing;
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 192.168.75.13;
        route 172.25.0.18/32 next-hop 172.16.41.182;
        route 172.25.0.19/32 next-hop 172.16.41.182;
    }
    router-id 192.168.100.1;
}
protocols {
    ospf {
        area 0.0.0.0 {
            interface irb.10;
            interface irb.1 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.4 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.2 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.5 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.6 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.8 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.9 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.15 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.111 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.100 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.172 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.141 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.11 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.130 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.311 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.140 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.133 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.132 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.176 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.331 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.332 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.334 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.136 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.20 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.212 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.3 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.211 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.213 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.230 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.231 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.232 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.234 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.236 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.210 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.138 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.238 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.338 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.170 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.180 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.188 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.288 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.388 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.380 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.370 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.270 {
                passive;
            }
            interface irb.280 {
                passive;
            }
        }
    }
    lldp {
        interface all;
    }
    lldp-med {
        interface all;
    }
    igmp-snooping {
        vlan default;
    }
    inactive: rstp {
        interface xe-0/0/0;
        interface xe-0/0/1;
        interface xe-0/0/2;
        interface xe-0/0/3;
        interface xe-0/0/4;
        interface xe-0/0/5;
        interface xe-0/0/6;
        interface xe-0/0/7;
        interface xe-0/0/8;
        interface xe-0/0/9;
        interface xe-0/0/10;
        interface xe-0/0/11;
        interface xe-0/0/12;
        interface xe-0/0/13;
        interface xe-0/0/14;
        interface xe-0/0/15;
        interface xe-0/0/16;
        interface xe-0/0/17;
        interface xe-0/0/18;
        interface xe-0/0/19;
        interface xe-0/0/20;
        interface xe-0/0/21;
        interface xe-0/0/22;
        interface xe-0/0/23;
        interface et-0/0/24;
        interface xe-0/0/24:0;
        interface xe-0/0/24:1;
        interface xe-0/0/24:2;
        interface xe-0/0/24:3;
        interface et-0/0/25;
        interface xe-0/0/25:0;
        interface xe-0/0/25:1;
        interface xe-0/0/25:2;
        interface xe-0/0/25:3;
        interface et-0/0/26;
        interface xe-0/0/26:0;
        interface xe-0/0/26:1;
        interface xe-0/0/26:2;
        interface xe-0/0/26:3;
        interface et-0/0/27;
        interface xe-0/0/27:0;
        interface xe-0/0/27:1;
        interface xe-0/0/27:2;
        interface xe-0/0/27:3;
    }
}
virtual-chassis {
    preprovisioned;
    member 0 {
        role routing-engine;
        serial-number TC3716430102;
    }
    member 1 {
        role routing-engine;
        serial-number PE3716350055;
    }
    member 2 {
        role line-card;
        serial-number PE3716350466;
    }
}
vlans {
    Backbone {
        vlan-id 10;
        l3-interface irb.10;
    }
    Central {
        vlan-id 5;
        l3-interface irb.5;
    }
    DEFAULT_VLAN {
        vlan-id 1;
        l3-interface irb.1;
    }
    DLVIDEO {
        vlan-id 141;
        l3-interface irb.141;
    }
    ES4thLab {
        vlan-id 311;
        l3-interface irb.311;
    }
    ESFac {
        vlan-id 380;
        l3-interface irb.380;
    }
    ESFacBYOD {
        vlan-id 388;
        l3-interface irb.388;
    }
    ESStu {
        vlan-id 370;
        l3-interface irb.370;
    }
    ES_BYOD {
        vlan-id 331;
        l3-interface irb.331;
    }
    ES_BYOD_Fac {
        vlan-id 332;
        l3-interface irb.332;
    }
    ES_Main_Wifi {
        vlan-id 334;
        l3-interface irb.334;
    }
    Fog {
        vlan-id 11;
        l3-interface irb.11;
    }
    HSFac {
        vlan-id 180;
        l3-interface irb.180;
    }
    HSFacBYOD {
        vlan-id 188;
        l3-interface irb.188;
    }
    HSPhone {
        vlan-id 140;
        l3-interface irb.140;
    }
    HSStu {
        vlan-id 170;
        l3-interface irb.170;
    }
    HS_BYOD_Fac {
        vlan-id 133;
        l3-interface irb.133;
    }
    HS_BYOD_Stu {
        vlan-id 132;
        l3-interface irb.132;
    }
    HighSchool {
        vlan-id 4;
        l3-interface irb.4;
    }
    JH {
        vlan-id 3;
        l3-interface irb.3;
    }
    JH107 {
        vlan-id 211;
        l3-interface irb.211;
    }
    JH116 {
        vlan-id 212;
        l3-interface irb.212;
    }
    JHFac {
        vlan-id 280;
        l3-interface irb.280;
    }
    JHFacBYOD {
        vlan-id 288;
        l3-interface irb.288;
    }
    JHOffice {
        vlan-id 213;
        l3-interface irb.213;
    }
    JHStu {
        vlan-id 270;
        l3-interface irb.270;
    }
    JH_BYOD_Fac {
        vlan-id 232;
        l3-interface irb.232;
    }
    JH_BYOD_Stu {
        vlan-id 231;
        l3-interface irb.231;
    }
    JH_Data {
        vlan-id 210;
        l3-interface irb.210;
    }
    JH_Faculty {
        vlan-id 234;
        l3-interface irb.234;
    }
    JH_Student {
        vlan-id 236;
        l3-interface irb.236;
    }
    JH_Wifi_APs {
        vlan-id 230;
        l3-interface irb.230;
    }
    KCISDFac_ES {
        vlan-id 338;
        l3-interface irb.338;
    }
    KCISDFac_HS {
        vlan-id 138;
        l3-interface irb.138;
    }
    KCISDFac_JH {
        vlan-id 238;
        l3-interface irb.238;
    }
    KHFac {
        vlan-id 130;
        l3-interface irb.130;
    }
    KHStu {
        vlan-id 136;
        l3-interface irb.136;
    }
    Scale {
        vlan-id 20;
        l3-interface irb.20;
    }
    SciAutoAGath {
        vlan-id 6;
        l3-interface irb.6;
    }
    VLAN172 {
        vlan-id 172;
        l3-interface irb.172;
    }
    VLAN176 {
        vlan-id 176;
        l3-interface irb.176;
    }
    VideoSur {
        vlan-id 100;
        l3-interface irb.100;
    }
    busbarn {
        vlan-id 9;
        l3-interface irb.9;
    }
    elem456 {
        vlan-id 15;
        l3-interface irb.15;
    }
    elementary {
        vlan-id 2;
        l3-interface irb.2;
    }
    hsmacser {
        vlan-id 8;
        l3-interface irb.8;
    }
    weather {
        vlan-id 111;
        l3-interface irb.111;
    }
}
```

The juniper at the junior high MDF is on port xe-0/0/23.

```
root@HSServerRoom-4600> show dhcp relay statistics
Packets dropped:
    Total                      127849
    Bootp packets              126744
    Interface not configured   588
    Bad UDP checksum           1
    No binding found           512
    dhcp-service total         4

Messages received:
    BOOTREQUEST                5571847
    DHCPDECLINE                142
    DHCPDISCOVER               1751818
    DHCPINFORM                 996327
    DHCPRELEASE                99599
    DHCPREQUEST                2723961

Messages sent:
    BOOTREPLY                  3999872
    DHCPOFFER                  968432
    DHCPACK                    3030802
    DHCPNAK                    638
    DHCPFORCERENEW             0

Packets forwarded:
    Total                      5737
    BOOTREQUEST                0
    BOOTREPLY                  5737
```

Comment: Thanks, Ron Maupin, for the markdown fix.  I haven't used the site to actually ask a question in ages.  I usually find where it was already asked and answered.

Comment: Whatever is handling routing for VLAN 288 needs to have a dhcp-relay agent configured to proxy requests to the main DHCP server. (or put an agent in the VLAN)

Comment: It would help if we knew which VLANs do not work with DHCP relay...

Comment: 288 and 280 seem to be the trouble makers right now. I swapped vlan 288 for vlan 236 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I did some more testing and it is working at the high school which is vlan 188 (10.1.88.0/21). I created the 170, 180, 188, 270, 280, 288, 370, 380, 388 VLANs all at the same time.  The 100s are high school, 200s are junior high and 300s are elementary.  The NOC is at high school and that is where the EX-4600 is.  Each campus has an EX-4300 in the respective MDF.  The difference between high school and junior high is the switches.  The AP that I am connected to right now goes [EX-4600]---[HP2824]---[HP2600]---[Meraki AP].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so aside from posting here I forwarded config scripts to a few network guys at Region 5 Education and they found the error.  On the EX-4300, which is between the EX-4600 and the HP-5130, I didn't do:

```
set vlans JHStu vlan-id 270
set vlans JHFac vlan-id 280
set vlans JHFacBYOD vlan-id 288
```

I had everything tagged/trunked on the ports, but the intermediary switch didn't know anything about the VLANs so it wouldn't pass the traffic.

Thanks, everyone, for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks correct from a dhcp-relay perspective.

If swapping the VLAN for 236 works, then the issue may be with the DHCP Scope for those two subnets on your DHCP server - check that your subnet mask on the server matches the irb interfaces that you have defined on the EX.

Comment: 10.41.88.2 - 10.41.95.254 is my address pool and 10.41.88.1 is my router. Unless I messed up I believe that is 10.41.88.0/21 which is what I have programmed in the switch.

Comment: Do you have captures of the traffic getting to/from the switch/dhcp server?

Comment: what output does show dhcp relay statistics show you?

Comment: Added show dhcp relay statistics to bottom of original question.

Comment: You seem to have dropped an awful lot of BOOTP requests - can you reset the counters and see if they continue to increment?

Comment: I will try it tomorrow when I am back at the office.